# Showing that $A_n$ is generated by the 3-cycles in $S_n$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, symmetric-groups

I am trying to show that $A_n$ is generated by the 3-cycles in $S_n$. It seems that every 3-cycle of the form $(a_1,a_2,a_3)$ can just be written as $(a_1,a_3)(a_1,a_2)$ so every 3-cycle turns into an even number of transpositions (2-cycles). Is this sufficient?

Comment: Nope, this is not sufficient. What you are showing is that $3$-cycles lie in $A_n$, not that they generate $A_n$.

Comment: Try writing $(a,b,c,d,e)$ as a product of $3$-cycles, for example.

Comment: (a,b,c,d,e) = (a,d,e)(a,b,c)?

Comment: In general $(a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_m)=(a_1,\ldots,a_k)(a_k,a_{k+1},\ldots,a_m)$. Iterating this lets you reduce a cycle to a product of transpositions. Knowing this makes it easier to use my answer to solve the problem.

Comment: I see, so perhaps the answer that Akiva Weinberger was looking for is that $(a,b,c,d,e) = (a,b,c)(c,d,e)$. Yes?

Comment: Probably, though I never checked your answer carefully, it could also be correct. Too late at night for me to be careful.

Comment: Fair enough but isn't it a straightforward consequence of the case $a_k = c$ in the generalization you cited?

Comment: I meant your original answer, (a,d,e)(a,b,c). While is not an example of the formula above, that doesn't necessarily mean it's wrong.

Comment: Indeed, it's correct and can be written instead as (d,e,a)(a,b,c), making it just like the formula.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An element of $A_n$ is a product of an even number of transpositions. For any pair of transpositions, find one or two 3-cycles whose product is equal to their product. After doing this you can generate all products of an even number of transpositions.

Answer (score 0):

Any element of the alternating group $\alpha \in A_n$ can be written as a product of an even number of transpositions with the decomposition $\alpha = (i_1 i_2 \dots i_r) = (i_1 i_r)(i_1 i_{r-1}) \dots (i_1 i_2)$ where $r$ is odd. Then we have that any pair of transpositions with a common element can be written as a 3-cycle $(i_1 i_k)(i_1 i_{k-1}) = (i_1 i_{k-1} i_k)$. By iterating on pairs of tranposition in the aforementioned decomposition, we can rewrite $\alpha$ as a product of 3-cycles.